# Internet not working when iptables INPUT rule = DROP

Tags: networking, iptables

I do not have an internet when I forbid all incoming traffic. Why? Here is the output from the terminal:

```
dev@dev-pc:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
dev@dev-pc:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=4.02 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=4.29 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=4.13 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.016/4.145/4.292/0.113 ms
dev@dev-pc:~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
dev@dev-pc:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
dev@dev-pc:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6146ms

dev@dev-pc:~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
dev@dev-pc:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=4.05 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.050/4.050/4.050/0.000 ms
dev@dev-pc:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 109.108.244.148  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 109.108.244.255
        inet6 fe80::b40:30c2:cb8:9e22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:08:22:b8:b5:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 124470  bytes 165771256 (165.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 66049  bytes 5942125 (5.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 132  bytes 11315 (11.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132  bytes 11315 (11.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ea:15:31:9c:86:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How to fix it???

Answer (score 1):

For your use case example, `ping 1.1.1.1`, 2 packets are involved per `ping`. An outgoing `ICMP echo request` packet and an **incoming** `ICMP echo reply` packet, at least if the destination does reply.

The succinct answer to your first question: "Why do I not have an internet when I forbid all incoming traffic?" is because you denied all incoming traffic, so nobody can respond.

Now, for your second question: "How to fix?":

iptables is capable of looking at a packet and determining if it is a reply or somehow **RELATED** to a previous outgoing, locally initiated, packet. Therefore you can make an iptables rule to allow this type of packet to get past the INPUT chain DROP default packet handler:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -d 109.108.244.148 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Note: you should also allow the local network connection, as sometimes internal tasks communicate via this interface:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Below is an example implementation of this answer, using your example pings:

```
doug@s18:~$ ping -c 2 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=24.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=25.9 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.597/25.260/25.923/0.663 ms

doug@s18:~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
doug@s18:~$ ping -c 2 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1061ms

doug@s18:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -d 192.168.111.122 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
doug@s18:~$ ping -c 2 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=24.9 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.911/25.012/25.113/0.101 ms
```